# Problem building the ROS android tutorials

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to build android_tutorial_pubsub and when it gets to actually building this, or any of the tutorials, It seems to search the ros dependencies for "None".  Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution>

I am rather out of ideas.  I have included the full output here:

```
rosrun rosjava_bootstrap make.py android_tutorial_pubsub
Buildfile: /home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/hg/android_tutorial_pubsub/dependencies.xml
[artifact:dependencies] There were no dependencies specified
[artifact:dependencies] There were no dependencies specified

get-dependencies:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
Skipping dependencies.xml generation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 110, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 104, in main
    build(rospack, package)
  File "/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/make.py", line 53, in build
    properties = ros_properties.generate(rospack, package, maven_depmap)
  File "/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/ros_properties.py", line 64, in generate
    properties['ros.pkg.%s.version' % (dependency)] = _get_package_version(dependency)
  File "/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap/src/main/python/rosjava_bootstrap/ros_properties.py", line 51, in _get_package_version
    roslib.stacks.get_stack_version(stack)) #@UndefinedVariable
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/stacks.py", line 310, in get_stack_version
    return get_stack_version_by_dir(get_stack_dir(stack, env=env))
  File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/roslib/stacks.py", line 168, in get_stack_dir
    raise InvalidROSStackException("Cannot location installation of stack %s. ROS_ROOT[%s] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[%s]"%(stack, env[ROS_ROOT], env.get(ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, '')))
roslib.stacks.InvalidROSStackException: Cannot location installation of stack None. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/electric/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/hg:/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/rosjava_core:/home/local/RESQUARED/kyle.visner/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks]
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10769/problem-building-the-ros-android-tutorials/) by [KVis](https://answers.ros.org/users/913/kvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a bug that has been fixed. Please update rosjava_core and the android repository.

---

Originally posted by [tpratkanis_wg](https://answers.ros.org/users/927/tpratkanis_wg/) with karma: 56 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1